# How to make wordpress use www.example.com/blog/wp-includes/ instead of www.example.com/wp-includes/?

Tags: url-rewriting

I have WordPress at address http://www.example.com/blog/, now I want it to be accessible as http://www.example.com/ without moving wordpress to root directory.

I have made appropriate .htaccess changes.

wp-config.php:

```
define("WP_HOME", "http://{$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]}");
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/blog/wp-content");
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', "http://{$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]}/blog/wp-content");
```

One thing that doesn't work is WordPress uses www.example.com/wp-includes/ instead of www.example.com/blog/wp-includes/

There are even includes like www.example.com/%post-name%/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2

I have fixed it through .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule wp-includes/(.*) /blog/wp-includes/$1 [L]
```

Is threre a better way?

Comment: I gave up. I think wordpress does not support using it this way.

Comment: Full tutorial how to do that is here http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to `wp-config.php`:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com/blog/');
```

On the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_address_.28URL.29).
This is all you need.

Comment: I want WP_SITEURL to be http://example.com/ That is where the problem comes from.

Comment: Read the documentation `WP_SITEURL` will only point to the folder where the WP files are. `WP_HOMEURL` points to the website in the browser.

Comment: Thanks, you pointed my error. I used site_url() in many places and that is the reason it didn't work for me.

Comment: Full solution - http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory